# ASP .NET entity framework project giving UnintentionalCodeFirstException after being published to azure

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, azure, ef-database-first

I have a ASP .Net project that I want to publish to Azure. At first, I did Enable-Migration and published the website by checking "Execute Code First Migration" check box in Publish Web dialog box in Visual Studio.

But I realized I am not using Code first approach since I have my DB already designed. I am using EF to create models for the database tables.

I deleted the Migrations folder from my project and republished the project WITHOUT checking the "Execute Code First Migration" for the database. But after publishing I still get this error:

[image]

What am i missing?

EDIT:

From web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-IMS2-20161228113511.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-IMS2-20161228113511;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />    
    <add name="IMSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.IMSEntities.csdl|res://*/Models.IMSEntities.ssdl|res://*/Models.IMSEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\Projects;initial catalog=IMS;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

From Azure portal. (Settings >> Application Settings >> Connection String). The name of the connection string in Azure is IMSEntitites.

```
Server=tcp:xxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=IMS;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=myUserName@xxxxxxxxx;Password=myPassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your connection string look like? ( you can remove the sensitive bits )

Comment: I have updated my question with the connection string from web.config file from project and the connection string generated in Azure

Comment: You may need to re-create your project.  Try this: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/create-dbcontext-in-entity-framework5.aspx